# In Hybris,can we start and stop a IBM JMS listener via a cronjob

Tags: jms, listener, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a requirement where we need to stop a listener from polling message from a queue at the same time we need to start another listener to read messages from separate queue.

In short both listeners should not be active at the same time.

How can we achieve this?

Can we develop a cronjob which will start/stop the Listener from polling respective queues at scheduled times?

Comment: Add the snippet of your configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of [DMLC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)(DefaultMessageListenerContainer), which allows stops/restarts as well as runtime changes to its configuration. All you need to do is inject its bean in your cronJob and perform stop/start method based on your input.

PS: I haven't tried it, but you can give a try!!